# MSMQ Receive method slowness

Tags: c#, .net, msmq

I'm hardly receiving 20~50 messages per second using MQ.Receive() method, as shown below.

```
private void ListenQueue()
    {
        while(true)
        {
            try
            {
                while(true)
                {
                    string aryRet = "";
                    System.Messaging.Message msg = InQueue.Receive();
                }
            }
            catch(Exception ex){/*log the exception*/}
        }
    }
```

I have done profiling and I see Receive() method is taking all the time, see below:

[image]

Comment: Please note that sender is sending like 1000 msgs per second or more...
I need to increase my MSMQ reading speed, so that i can process more messages per second.
Thanks

Comment: Temporarily disable the installed anti-malware product and measure again.

Comment: What is the approximate size of the messages? Are you processing the received message on the same thread? What we see from the profiling output is that only 11% of the (cpu time? wall clock time?) is spent in ListenQueue(). Please add more details.

Comment: Could you try using [async receive](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.messaging.messagequeue.beginreceive?view=netframework-4.8)?

Comment: Message size is not more than 500 bytes....
sender is a separate application, receiver is a separate app.. 
11% time is CPU time

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add "urgent" or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) and find out why it often has the opposite effect.